# CSRF Issue in HTML Form Tag for Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, forms, csrf, static-analysis

Even though all the API calls are being protected with auth tokens, Security application on static code analysis throughs CSRF in all the form tags(HTML files) used in Angular application. Google-> It only talks about generating CSRF but no where on the bypassing this. Thanks in advance.

Refereed:
[How does Angular handle XSS or CSRF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594516/how-does-angular-handle-xss-or-csrf)

https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/angular-csrf-protection-guide-examples-and-how-to-enable-it/

[Angular 2: add csrf parameter to noNgForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666205/angular-2-add-csrf-parameter-to-nongform)

[How to add CSRF token to Angular 8 post request from Django 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266828/how-to-add-csrf-token-to-angular-8-post-request-from-django-2-2)

[Angular 6 does not add X-XSRF-TOKEN header to http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510998/angular-6-does-not-add-x-xsrf-token-header-to-http-request)

[How to add assign csrf token in the HTML submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527120/how-to-add-assign-csrf-token-in-the-html-submit-form)

Comment: im also having this exact problem, did you manage to get a solution?

Comment: Nope, I'm not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody ever needs a fix for this, what worked for me was replacing my `<form>` tags with `<div>` tags.

Of course, `[name]` attributes are only valid on `<form>` tags, but the important `[formGroup]` attribute ([docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#grouping-form-controls)) I was using to link the form in the template to the data in the component is valid. So maybe it's not a very proper way to go about it, but it didn't affect functionality at all, and it satisfied our static analysis tool.